# Laravel websocket, stream the entire model with relations constantly

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

I'm creating a live restaurant app, my goal is to stream data constantly from the database,

Meaning some items will constantly change is_active column from false to true and vice versa and i want the users to have the up to date data all the time

I am using Laravel-websockets with pusher

So far I only managed to connect to WS and send event that signalizes the FE app to refetch the data, which is kind of inefficent in large number of users